# Write to MS Access DB located on shared drive from Web Form

Tags: ms-access

I am pretty sure the answer is "No" but I figured I would ask because I was not able to find a solid answer.

I am trying to create a web form that would write to an MS Access database that is stored on a Shared Network Drive. Is this something that is possible without a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. *Web forms* require a *web server* to run (specifically, SharePoint server).

Interfacing with Access on a shared network drive is possible (either directly through Access or through another application), but not through a web form.

Comment: That is what I figured...I just wanted to make sure I was thorough in my investigation. Thanks to all for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ODBC DNS to access a MS Access file that is share on a drive.

Comment: Would this work for a multi-user environment? From a brief investigation it looks like it would need to be configured on each machine.

Comment: Yeah you would need to configure the ODBC DSN on each client machine